# sticky header function not well

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, iphone

when scrolling down header should not be visible, just after scrolling up header will be visible. my code work for iPhone well but on other mobile devices like samsung, nexus.... it don't. while scrolling down it shows my sticky header and this what i don't want.

any ideas how i can solve thos problem?

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
  var lastPos = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (pos > lastPos || pos == 0) {
      // scroll down
      $(".backButton").attr('data-position','');
    } else {
      // scroll up
      $(".backButton").attr('data-position','fixed');
    }
    lastPos = pos;  
  });
});
```

```css
.backButton {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  max-width: 100%;
  webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
}

.backButton[data-position=fixed] {
  left: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 16px;
  top: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="backButton">
  <a href="#" class="backLink">BACK</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't `.backButton[data-position=fixed]` supposed to be `.backButton[data-position="fixed"]`, as per standards?

Comment: Can't you just use `$(".backButton").css('position','fixed');` and `$(".backButton").css('position','relative');` or just give it a completely different class with `$(".backButton").toggleClass( "[yourclass]" );`